# Can powered speakers actually send any Power/audio OUT of the input jack?

Tags: desktop-computer

Thanks in advance for reading .So is there any chance that reverse current is sent back by old speakers,from speakers audio Input Jack to motherboard's green audio port and affecting/damaging the system?

Answer (score 2):

Just speakers, not with any kind of integrated amplifier -

Short answer, No.

Long answer, yes, but the tiniest tiniest amount.
A speaker uses the same principle as a microphone - electromagnetic induction.
Both use a magnet & a coil of wire. If you supply a voltage to a coil of wire, it produces a magnetic field. This then causes the coil to be pushed or pulled relative to the magnet. Inversely, if you move a coil in proximity to a magnet, it will produce electricity... that's the principle on which most microphones & speakers work.

However... the current produced is so small that it will not damage anything. In fact, unless you had some pretty specialist equipment, you wouldn't even be able to measure the amount of current generated by a speaker if you tap it to create movement.

---

On the other hand, if you have any kind of powered amplification in the speaker housing, then normally the answer would still be No.
Only if something had gone badly wrong/physically broken in the circuitry could higher voltage than normal be pushed back towards your other equipment.

Comment: And anything that's active and does it is badly designed and might be releasing magic smoke soon. Not sure if anything passive would do that without massive damage to all the right places.

Comment: A late thought - a powered speaker running from a wall-wart switch-mode supply might have sufficient leakage to show at the input terminals - but hopefully not sufficient to allow the magic smoke to escape.

Comment: Yeah, but that's 'active' and has said integrated amplifiers. TBH, magic smoke escaping without damaging the main system is a *good* thing. Speakers are cheap, and you can buy tolerable sets for 20 or so quid. Computers on the other hand...

Comment: "Speakers are cheap"... well, some are. Mine cost more than most people's computers... they also run directly on mains voltage -  but I'm an audio engineer, so that's my excuse ;)

Comment: Speakers(2 spk. & 1 woofer sys.) are old,of 2007,And the power ADAPTER fell on the ground a few times in the past.So thats why I m here for help and the speaker even in off condition produces crackling sound,maybe due to potentiometer sliding over dust...but worried about motherboard damage and affect performance...